# Make a Latching double pole single throw relay, using electronic components

Tags: relay, power-electronics, electrical, latching-relay

I am latching a DPST relay. So I made a prototype using some transistors(ex. BC547) to enabling and disabling the latching. But I want to know whats the correct way of doing it. I have both 12V and 24V relays. And make a complete isolation to the micro controller.

Comment: Normally if you want to latch a relay, you buy a latching relay so it latches even when power is removed. Electronic solutions can't do that.

Comment: Yes, But I am told to use DPST Relay. Because for any reason if the relays fails it should not give power to the load connected to it.(For Safety.)

Comment: so you are using a DPDT relay to latch itself and now you want to give a microcontoller control over this relay?

Comment: @Jasen Yes, and also want to know the proper way of latching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible ways of 'latching' a relay electronically.
The method below is one of many - whether it suits depends on the detailed requirement.

Input C will

- latch the relay on when pulsed high,
- allow the relay to remain in it's last "driven state when left floating and
- Unlatch / deoperate the relay when pulsed low

Or, separate latch and unlatch inputs may be used.

Input B will

- latch the relay on when pulsed high, and
- not affect the relay when floated or held low.

Input A will

- unlatch / deactivate the relay when pulsed low, and
- not affect the relay when floated or held high.

The "sense" / polarity of any input can be altered by placing a simple inverter (similar to R4 & Q1) before the input.

Inputs A B C have to provide enough current to overcome the latching current provided by R3. D1 would ideally be a Schottky diode to allow input A to pull Q1-base low enough in all situations.

The relay is shown as SPST but may have other contact configurations as desired.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyjo9d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Turn on:**

R4 input high turns on Q1.
Q1 on pulls R1 low, turns on Q2.
Q2 on pulls R3 and relay high.  Relay now on.
Q2 on via R3 turns or holds Q1 on.

**Latch / float:**

Any or all of of the following input states have no effect on Q1 which remains latched by Q2 via R3. Inputs :

- C floating (high impedance),
- A high or
- B low

**Delatch / Off.**

Either of
 - A low or
 - C low
grounds Q1 base via R4 and as R4 is << R3 turns off Q1. 
This turns off 2 and relay and pullup/latch path via R3.

For proper turn-off with A low, D1 should be a Schottky diode.
Then R4-left say 0.3V. Vb_Q1 ~= 0.3 + (Vcc-0.3) x (R4/R4+R3)
For eg Vcc = 5V
Vb_Q1 = 0.3 + 4.7 x 1k/(34k) = 0.44 V = OK
R3 can be larger if Vcc is larger, eg 100K for Vcc=12V
(Vcc = 12V, R3 = 100k, Vb_Q1 = 0.42V.

At higher Vcc levels, Dopt1, Ropt1 can be added for extra delatch certainty if desired.

Comment: I was using DPST relays as the relay will act as latching itself. But your circuit eliminates that. I am new to electronics, So would please explain the working of the circuit.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Just a question: Why the diode in series with the base of the transistor?  Not a criticism, just curious.  I use this type of circuit all the time and adjust voltage thresholds with resistor ratios.

Comment: @DwayneReid (1) As noted - Diode optional :-) (2) Without diode, with D1=Schottky, R4-left is say 0.3V. This is (as I know you know) somewhat arbitrary, but a starting point. As noted, for higher Vcc at top of pullup you need to up R3 to keep Q1b below conduction. As per calc - at 12V Vcc you get 0.4x V Which is below nominal Vbe on - but not much higher you are starting to get a whisper of Ic AND Q2 may start to pay a little attention AND you have R3 positive feedback So while it can be designed, it's a bit closer to the edge worst case than may sometimes be wise, Murphy lurking as he does...

Comment: SO by adding Dopt1 you need to get R4-left to the better part of 0.6V before Q1b even thinks about coming off ground, and to get to say even 0.3V you need about 0.9V at R4 left - which you are NEVER going to get with a Schottky at D1 nor even with a silicon diode. SO Dopt1 gives you the additional 0.6V headroom which means R3 can be just about any value you like regardless of Vcc value. - As noted Dopt is optional -  but, Murphy would hate it. (It more or less removes the need to design the R3 divider). [[Critique of that argument is VERY welcome]].

Answer (score 0):

A common self-latching relay circuit often used for machine control is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZyuWt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

Pressing the "Start" button will operate the relay and apply power to the coil through the lower contact, so the relay remains on when the Start button is released.  The upper contact applies power to the load.

Pressing the Stop button will break the power feed to the lower contact so the relay  will release, breaking power to the load.  If the incomming power is lost the relay will also be released, so power will not be applied to the load when incomming power is restored.

Comment: Yes, I was looking similar to this. But what in my use case was, I used transistors for the stop and start switch. And the Load was connected to the last two terminals,which was a AC power Supply.

Comment: @PeterBennet: The NC Stop switch is more commonly in series with the relay coil so that it functions as a fail-safe STOP command.

Comment: @Peter He wants an isolated controlled contact - which of course your relay gives him just by breaking the connection to line.

Comment: How do I implement electronic control instead of the switches in this Case.