# Need help with a state change circuit

Tags: digital-logic

I am a novice when it comes to electrical engineering and design. I am trying to find a circuit that will sense a change (high to low or low to high) and momentarily close a relay. In the bigger picture I want to use a BT dongle in my car and a BT receiver on my gate and or garage door opener to open/close the gate or door.

When the BT dongle comes in range, the 2 will pair and send a high or low (not sure just yet) and I would like that to trigger a momentary output to close a switch (or in this case, a relay). The same in reverse, when the 2 get out of range of each other and unpair, the switch will again momentarily to trigger the gate or garage door to close.

Comment: You might be looking for a monostable circuit.

Comment: burrism - Hi, Stack Exchange has different rules from typical forums (please see the [tour] & [help]). You posted an answer to say thank you - that's not allowed here and was deleted, sorry. Please see this article in the [help] called: "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](/help/someone-answers)" and follow the guidance there. If you need clarification on an answer, you can comment on that answer. Otherwise, consider upvoting useful answers (your votes will be visible when you have more points) and consider [áccepting](/help/accepted-answer) your choice of best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 'timer relay' or latching relays (with limit switches) for this purpose.  A momentary trigger input command tells the relay to latch 'on' for a certain amount of time.  Another timer relay (or 'time delay relay') can be used for your closing operation as well.

Alternatively, if timimg seems too sketchy, use simple latching relays (with limit switches on your gate) to control the gate.

Latching relays can be bought as a unit, or you can make them like so:
[Make a Latching double pole single throw relay, using electronic components](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/477161/make-a-latching-double-pole-single-throw-relay-using-electronic-components)

Googles brought up this video (of which I have no connection to the author, other than his apparent work hangover), that illustrates things plainly.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZb3mFATxx8
[image]

The control logic will still be up to you, and as you plan on using BlueTooth, you likely already have the programming chops to handle that.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think that I did not explain my idea correctly. I have a gate opening system that requires a momentary closed switch to activate and I am wanting to convert the bluetooth output that turns on an LED, as long as the two devices are within range, into a momentary output. And when the devices are not in range, the output has changed and use that state change to convert to a momentary output. Right now, the BT module will turn on an LED when the devices pair and turn it off when they unpair. I want to convert that output to momentary pulses, like a momentary switch.

Comment: Then check out the classic Monostable ("one-shot") multivibrator circuits.  The 74xx121 may be suitable.  These circuits 'trigger' when either a rising or falling edge is detected (you decide), and can also provide both positive and negative-going outputs.  You would need to pick the proper logic series that is compatible with your bluetooth widget (the voltage and drive levels), and also craft the interface from the monostable outputs to your gate driver.

Answer (score 0):

In this simple circuit the edge detection is created using two R/C elements, C1/R1 for the rising edge and C2/R2 for the falling edge. The MOSFETS are conducting for around 200 ms after the corresponding edge until the gate voltage (Vgs) falls below the threshold voltage again.

However, the circuit behaviour is undefined on power on. It is possible, that both relays will turn on for a short period if V_IN is floating at that time.

V3, R3 and R4 are just added to show a proper simulator output of the relay contact response.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftQ8Rn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>